# Loading ajax data on scroll instead of pager with TableSorter

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

Currently using Tablesorter for loading data from server. The default function that pager uses is to load new data from server and discard what's there in the page. I would like to implement unlimited scroll.

I was looking at **widget-paper.js**

```
if ( $.isFunction( wo.pager_ajaxProcessing ) ) {  
            c.$tbodies.eq( 0 ).empty();
```

**c.$tbodies.eq(0).empty()** - This function handles the ajax request. I removed the below code and works fine but then this messes with other stuff. Can anyone help or may have implemented it ? I am not looking to use datatable for now. Can

Comment: You can view to this link may be useful and help you: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/docs/example-pager-ajax.html

Comment: Thanks @FerasAlSous but m not sure you got my point. I am looking for something like this https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: There is no current method of doing this with tablesorter.

Comment: @Mottie may be you can take this into a feature request ?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1419... it's in progress!